# MFT File entry having multiple Filename attributes and a Reparse point

Tags: ntfs, ntfs-mft

I am reading MFT Entries of NTFS file system.

I know that MFT can have multiple FileName attributes, which are created when we create hard links. I know that Junctions/Symbolic links can be created for directories. Junction / Symbolic link are implemented using Reparse points.

While reading a VHD file formatted with NTFS filesystem, I find that there are some MFT entries for "Directories" having multiple Filename attributes and single Reparse point.

Is it possible for directories to have hardlinks (and more than one?). Below is the actual MFT Record. and screenshot. How do we create such record in MFT with mklink tool?

[image]

```
        0x46, 0x49, 0x4c, 0x45, 0x30, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0xe3, 0xaf, 0x03, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x04, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x38, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x88, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x14, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x02, 0x00, 0x5c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0xe8, 0xe7, 0x87, 0xf8, 0x0a, 0xbb, 0xd0, 0x01, 0xe8, 0xe7, 0x87, 0xf8, 0x0a, 0xbb, 0xd0, 0x01,
        0xab, 0xe1, 0xdc, 0x00, 0x89, 0x5e, 0xd1, 0x01, 0xe8, 0xe7, 0x87, 0xf8, 0x0a, 0xbb, 0xd0, 0x01,
        0x06, 0x24, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x73, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x78, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x5e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00,
        0x95, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xab, 0xe1, 0xdc, 0x00, 0x89, 0x5e, 0xd1, 0x01,
        0xab, 0xe1, 0xdc, 0x00, 0x89, 0x5e, 0xd1, 0x01, 0xab, 0xe1, 0xdc, 0x00, 0x89, 0x5e, 0xd1, 0x01,
        0xab, 0xe1, 0xdc, 0x00, 0x89, 0x5e, 0xd1, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x0e, 0x01, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x63, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x53, 0x00,
        0x65, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x69, 0x00, 0x6e, 0x00, 0x67, 0x00, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00,
        0x52, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x95, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00,
        0xe8, 0xe7, 0x87, 0xf8, 0x0a, 0xbb, 0xd0, 0x01, 0xe8, 0xe7, 0x87, 0xf8, 0x0a, 0xbb, 0xd0, 0x01,
        0xab, 0xe1, 0xdc, 0x00, 0x89, 0x5e, 0xd1, 0x01, 0xe8, 0xe7, 0x87, 0xf8, 0x0a, 0xbb, 0xd0, 0x01,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x06, 0x24, 0x00, 0x10, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x08, 0x02, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x4f, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00,
        0x41, 0x00, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x53, 0x00, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x90, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00,
        0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x24, 0x00, 0x49, 0x00, 0x33, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00,
        0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xb0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00,
        0x94, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x8c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0x00, 0x46, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x00, 0x5c, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00,
        0x43, 0x00, 0x3a, 0x00, 0x5c, 0x00, 0x55, 0x00, 0x73, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x73, 0x00,
        0x5c, 0x00, 0x44, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x66, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0x75, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00,
        0x5c, 0x00, 0x41, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x44, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00,
        0x5c, 0x00, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x63, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00,
        0x3a, 0x00, 0x5c, 0x00, 0x55, 0x00, 0x73, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x73, 0x00, 0x5c, 0x00,
        0x44, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x66, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0x75, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x5c, 0x00,
        0x41, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x44, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0x5c, 0x00,
        0x4c, 0x00, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x63, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0x6c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x82, 0x79, 0x47, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00,
```

Answer (score 0):

These are hard links corresponding to 8.3 file naming convention. If you look closely, every directory entries with reparse attribute has a ~ symbol in its name. Also, you can see that the reparse attribute is only present in the second file name attribute.